# How to delete data from MySQL database using sequelize based on time?

Tags: mysql, node.js, authentication, sequelize.js

I want to delete otp automatically, from the database after 3 minutes. using sequelize.
I am trying this way

```
let delOtp = await Otp.destroy({ where: {createdAt: createdAt < '2021-12-20'}})
        if (delOtp) {
            res.status(200).json({ message: "otp deleted" })
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ message: "not deleted", data: err})
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to change your condition to:

```js
{ where: { createdAt: { [Op.gt]: '2021-12-20' } } }
```

Look at [official documentation: Operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators)